# Cannot modify managed objects outside of a write transaction || Realm .Net SDK

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

**Realms.Exception.RealmInvalidTransactionException: Cannot modify managed objects outside of a write transaction**

I was using Ream .Net SDK 10.13 and recently updated it to 10.19.0. After, the update I am frequently getting the above error.

Here is an example of how I am using it in my Xamarin Forms project

```
public class TestClass: RealmObject
{
//Class properties are defined 
// as per the realm docs, proper attributes 
//are added for Kets and mapping

}
```

Now in some class/view models, where I have an instance of the TestClass injected through the constructor

```
public async Task<SomeUserDefinedType> SomeMethod(TestClass item){

var realm = Realms.Realm.GetInstance();
await realm.WriteAsync(async()=>{
 // setting property of the TestClass
item.SomeProperty = "Some Value";
});
 return <Instance of SomeUserDefinedType>;
}
```

The above method call gives an exception. Above code is modified as per the new version.
The below code was as per the older version which was working fine but it started giving the same exception after the update

```
public async Task<SomeUserDefinedType> SomeMethod(TestClass item){

await item.WriteAsync(async i =>{
 // setting property of the TestClass
  i.SomeProperty = "Some Value";
});
 return <Instance of SomeUserDefinedType>;
}
```

I tried many ways to resolve this issue but none is working.
Any Suggestions/Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The code is not really clear - where does `item` come from? Is it possible it's from a  realm on a different thread?

Comment: @Jay Item is coming from the same thread.

Comment: We need to see the stack trace reported by the exception. At which point the code that you show needs to have the real names otherwise the stack trace is not gonna be useful. Finally, SO is not the best place to dig into an issue like forums are. So, it'd be best if you open a question on the [MongoDB forum](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/).